# Relational DB : is it a bad practice to store data on relationships?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relationship

I work for a firm with a relational database. Some of my colleagues once told me that storing data directly on relationships (and not on entities) was a bad pratice. I can't remember why. Can you help me with that ? Do you agree ? What are the risks ?

Many thanks !

Comment: you question is not clear  .. try add  a data sample

Comment: Ok, for instance : a have a pack (products a user put in his cart) with some materials. Each one is an entity with specific info (name, priceTTC,...). Could I put information about the material on the relationship PackMaterial ?

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling & database design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.) PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please research before you consider posting a question--see [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a bad practice.  In fact, "relationships" are often entities themselves.  For instance, an "order" might relate a "person" and "store".  It would also naturally have other information such as when the purchase happened, the payment amount, the total amount, and so on.

In general, when I create tables in SQL, I include information such as:

- `createdAt` -- the date/time the row was created
- `createdBy` -- who created the row
- `createdOn` -- the system where the row was created

This would be true on all tables, even those representing many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! And what do you think about specific info about Material ? Like putting materials' price directly on the relationship Pack/Material ?

Comment: What if you have multiple prices? I.E. "Regular" price vs "Sales" price? What if you have multiple vendors that you buy materials from... with different pricing for you? You would probably want a separate table to hold all the prices for an item. And a separate one for the purchasing prices too (perhaps), relating to your vendors. These concepts are related to your business *requirements*. Not necessarily driven by "best practices".

Comment: @JacobH . . . I would argue that meeting business requirements is pretty much the definition of "best practices".